# Switch between game levels in pyGame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

TL;DR- It is telling me that the global variable 'main' is not defined, is there a way to call main from within another class in another file? -

I am creating a small platformer game for my CS class and for the second half of the assignment where we customize the game I want to add a second level. When you "hit" the "door" type tile I was thinking I could re-run main like so.

Here is main and below is the collision test and return

```
def main():

    if level == 1:
        p = Platformer('Adventure Time!', 'map1.tmx', 600, 600, 30)
    else:
        p = Platformer('Adventure Time!', 'map2.tmx', 600, 600, 30)
    p.main_loop()

main()
```

Next within the player class where collisions with different objects are detected I run this code when I hit a "door" type

```
def handleCollisionWith(self, name, other):

    if other.kind == 'door':
        level = 'level2'
        main()
```

It is telling me that the global variable 'main' is not defined, is there a way to call main from within another class in another file?

Comment: You will get: `main()` call `main()` which call `main()` etc. so you will get `mainloop()` inside `mainloop()` which is inside `mainloop()` etc. Your game has incorrect construction. `handleCollisionWith` should leave `Platformer` to get back to first `main()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
def main(level): #note i added the level parameter that you have to pass in
    if level == "level1":
        p = Platformer('Adventure Time!', 'map1.tmx', 600, 600, 30)
    else:
        p = Platformer('Adventure Time!', 'map2.tmx', 600, 600, 30)
    p.main_loop()


def handleCollisionWith(self, name, other):
    if other.kind == 'door':
        level = 'level2'
        Class_name.main(level) #you have to call main() with reference to the class it is in
```